# Isosceles trapezoid bases

Tags: geometry

I have a question that involves the isosceles trapezoid as below. I need to find how much bigger the area of $B$ is compared to the area of $A$. I tried many ways but could not figure out. can anyone give me a hint to this question? Thanks!

[image: Isosceles trapezoid question link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the height of the trapezoid by dropping a line from the ends of the $19$ to the base and using the created right triangles and trig.  Find the slant side of the trapezoid using Pythagoras or trig.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer!!